# What makes a wave dispersive?

Tags: waves, dispersion

Water waves are [dispersive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_%28water_waves%29) ( longer wavelengths travel faster ) but sound waves in air are not, otherwise we would listen first the high frequencies and the low frequencies after.

What decides if a wave will be dispersive or not?

This question has been asked again. I am looking for an answer or a comment that explains the physical reasons behind the mathematics.

Comment: The physical reason is that you have not paid attention:  sound most certainly disperses in air.  Listen to a thunderclap: first you hear a high crack, then later on a low rumbling.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its assumptions are wrong

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Why not, you are right. But the essence of the question is why waves are dispersive

Comment: I think the medium can be dispersive (or not), not the wave

Comment: @fpdx I admit this as well. What makes a medium dispersive?

Comment: "What makes a medium dispersive?" seems to be the essence of the original question. As discussed below, a medium can be dispersive if it has some natural frequency that governs the medium's response to incident frequencies. The natural frequency is determined by the physical constraints on the medium's constituent bodies.

Comment: Strike my last. Based on veronica's comments on this page, it seems the original question was about dispersion of sound and less so about dispersion in general.

Comment: Closing questions because the *assumptions* are wrong? Why not *correct* those assumptions with an answer instead?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I think thunder is a bad example since it derives from a shock wave, which is nonlinear and can be dispersive by definition.  I agree that sound waves can be weakly dispersive, but one can usually get away with assuming the dispersionless approximation of sound waves...

Comment: @honeste_vivere  "shock wave is dispersive by definition..." ?? only if the shock is hypersonic.   And you most certainly cannnot ignore sonic dispersion over distances greater than a few hundred meters or so.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Sorry, I was thinking about the idea of nonlinear wave steeping, which would be dependent upon density, pressure, etc. and could refract under varying conditions.  Thus, the medium could cause the wave to disperse in that way...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Dispersion of sound in air, with constant temperature and pressure, is very slight, increasing for very short wavelengths, and for very loud noises. Why? Because the rapid sequence of weak compression/decompression steps as the sound propagates are [adiabatic](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/adiab.html#c1), or energy-conserving, for the normal ranges of sound. This leaves the local pressure, temperature and density unchanged.

As a result, the equation for the speed of sound in an [ideal gas](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sound/souspe3.html#c1) is $c^2 = \gamma P/\rho$, with $c$ the speed of sound, $\gamma$ is the adiabatic constant for the gas, $P$ the gas pressure, and $\rho$ the gas density; other formulas are equivalent. Note that intensity and frequency do not appear in this equation.  Hence sound is non-dispersive over wide ranges, given stable atmospheric conditions.

Sometimes thunder is given as a counter-example, where a variety of sounds are heard following a [lightning strike](http://stormhighway.com/thunderc.php) but this is not due to dispersion; rather it is the multiple branches of the pre-strike, the main strike, and the extended distances covered by the lightning, plus, sometimes, echos.

Light is similarly non-dispersive in the ordinary atmosphere, but changes in pressure, temperature, and humidity change that, hence mirages.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at Griffiths Introduction to Electrodynamics, particularly the section called "The Frequency Dependence of Permittivity".

Dispersion can arise from the constraints, or bound nature, of the constituent particles in a given medium. For the example of optical dispersion in a dielectric medium, we could picture the electrons as bound, damped oscillators to which a passing light wave applies a driving force. These oscillators have a natural frequency and, depending on the closeness of the light wave's frequency to the natural frequency, the response of the system will vary-- for instance, more or less energy will be absorbed from the passing light wave.